# Vuejs set method return to template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm new to Vue and I'm stuck at the moment. For the practice I'm making an app for episode checklist for series. The first part of the app searches series and add one of them to a database. Result for the search gives me a result like this:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuOfc.png

Heres my code with template and script:

```
<template>
  <div class="series">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="item in series" :key="item.id">
        <img :src="image_url+item.poster_path"/>
        <div class="info">
          {{item.name}}
          <br/>
          <h5>{{item.id}}</h5>
          Start Date: {{item.first_air_date}}
          <br/>
          {{getEpisodeNumber(item.id)}}
          <br/>
          {{getSeasonNumber(item.id)}}
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "series",
  props: ["series"],
  data() {
    return {
      image_url: "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500",
      api_key: {-api key-},
      episode_url: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/",
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async getEpisodeNumber(showID) {
      const json = await fetch(this.episode_url + showID + this.api_key)
        .then((res) => { return res.json() })
        .then((res) => { return res.number_of_episodes })
      return await json
    },
    async getSeasonNumber(showID) {

      const json = await fetch(this.episode_url + showID + this.api_key)
        .then((res) => { return res.json() })
        .then((res) => { return res.number_of_seasons })
      return await json;
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Methods should return to me a number but they return an object, probably promise object. But when I try to console.log the data in the methods they print a value(int). I need reach this value but I'm stuck. I tried to sort of thinks but it fails every time.

Comment: what variable did you print in console.log?

Comment: It won't be possible because you are using async and it always return a promise

Comment: Your best solution would be to create a sub component and just pass the item in there and inside the sub-component, you can assign data variable for the season and episode number, so when you use fetch to get the data, you just need to set the value of the season number and episode number

Comment: Why don't you simply await the promises? Like so:
res = await fetch()
json = await.json()
num = json.number

Comment: @Phoenix I print `res.number_of_episodes` and `res.number_of_seasons `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just create a new component called `show` and pass `item.id` to this component. In `show` component, I use another `fetch()` to get show data again and now it works like I want.